# Improving speed of barcode scanning iOS8

Tags: performance, ios8, barcode

In iOS8 we inform the types of barcode that should be recognized as indicated below.

```
self.acceptedBarcodeTypes = [NSMutableArray new];
[self.acceptedBarcodeTypes addObject:@"org.iso.QRCode"];
[self.acceptedBarcodeTypes addObject:@"org.iso.PDF417"];
[self.acceptedBarcodeTypes addObject:@"org.gs1.UPC-E"];
[self.acceptedBarcodeTypes addObject:@"org.iso.Aztec"];
[self.acceptedBarcodeTypes addObject:@"org.iso.Code39"];
[self.acceptedBarcodeTypes addObject:@"org.iso.Code39Mod43"];
[self.acceptedBarcodeTypes addObject:@"org.gs1.EAN-13"];
[self.acceptedBarcodeTypes addObject:@"org.gs1.EAN-8"];
[self.acceptedBarcodeTypes addObject:@"com.intermec.Code93"];
[self.acceptedBarcodeTypes addObject:@"org.iso.Code128"];
```

If we reduce the number of types are you having a significantly performance enhancement in terms of barcode recognition or it doesn't matter?

Comment: have you tried to make any performance tests yet? why not?

Comment: I don't think it's straightforward to design a proper performance test since it depend on illumination, barcode size, motion, etc. My question was directed to check if there's a canonical way of doing it

Comment: Generally speaking having less barcode recognizers active will consume less processor cycles and scanning will be faster. If you are asking for speed then you have observed some issues. For better understanding you might give more details.